# DOMSubtreeModified doesn't fire on $.hide() and $.show()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

[**jsfiddle example link**](http://jsfiddle.net/LUUrE/5/)

Seems like jQuery `$.hide()` and `$.show()` do not modify the DOM to hide/show the element, and hence do not fire `DOMSubtreeModified` event. How can I capture those kind of events on any element on the DOM?

**UPDATE:**
The code doesn't work on Chrome16 Ubuntu. Originally, I need to target QT browser, which is based on Webkit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are correct, `DOMSubtreeModified` is purely for *modifications* so you have a few choices:

1) use `DOMAttrModified` which has just as bad if not  worse support than `DOMSubtreeModified`

2) override the `.hide()` and `.show()` methods in jQuery so you can capture any calls to them and respond:

```
var oldShow = $.fn.show;
$.fn.show = function(args) {
    alert('showing!');
    oldShow.apply(this, arguments);
};
// do the same for .hide()
```

3) run some kind of "monitor" in a loop (eg. `setInterval()`), looking at the visible children counts or something to that affect

4) re-organize the way you are thinking about the problem...

hope this helps -ck

Answer (score 2):

Your example JSFiddle works for me in Chrome 17. I believe your problem is a browser support one. I'm not sure of the exact browser support but not all browsers support the `DOMSubtreeModified` event. I do know that `DOMSubtreeModified` is not supported in IE8.

And `.hide()`/`.show()` alter the elements `style` attribute, adding `display:none`/`display:(block|list-item|etc.)`

### Update

I recommend triggering a custom event on element you alter, then listening for that event:

```
//register event handler
$(document).on('customDOMAltered', function (event) {
    console.log(event.target);
});

//alter DOM element
$('#some-element').hide().trigger('customDOMAltered');
```

Comment: I know it does modify style attr, but for some reason, it doesn't work on chrome 16 ubuntu... Originally, I will need to support QT browser, which is based on webkit.

Comment: @shershams I would recommend doing something like triggering a custom event on an element when you change it, then listening for your custom event instead, this will work in all browsers.

Comment: It would definitely work, but the issue is, I'm writing a plugin code to check third party code. There are some policies they should follow and I will need to enforce it if they don't. I don't have control over what they code, but I can check what they display on DOM change.